# C# how to prevent disappearing last chart label

Tags: c#, charts, label

I'm creating windows form application. In one form there is only chart which displays values from list. In some cases all x axis labels are displayed, but in another, chart resizes and last label dissapears. I was trying to set IsEndLabelVisible=true, IsLabelAutoFit=true. Nothing helps. Does anyone know how to prevent that? Thanks in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD14l.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aGJ9.jpg)

Comment: set your : chartArea.AxisX.Interval = 1; and chartArea.AxisX.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
chartArea.AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.LabelsAngleStep30;